# Why Java StringWriter close method throws IOException?

Tags: java, autocloseable, stringwriter

I wonder why Java designers made `close()` method on `StringWriter` throwing the `IOException`, when it actually does nothing. E.g. in `PrintWriter`, the exceptions are suppressed even though the `PrintWriter` really can do something when it uses an appropriate `Writer`.
Wouldn't it make sense to make `StringWriter.close` method throwing nothing? Or does current solution have some reason?

Motivation:

```
try (final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
){
    // ...
}
```

I have to handle `IOException` since the close method is being to be called by the try-with-resources block. Of course I can place `StringWriter` before the try-with-resources block, but why to do it since it's an autocloseable ;-).

Comment: I _feel_ like overriding methods _used to_ have to keep the exceptions thrown by the overridden method in their own signatures, and that this only became optional afterwards, but I can't manage to confirm my guess. But yeah, I'd say that this is so because of legacy :)